# Convert Long Lat to pixel vector from origin point

Tags: unity-game-engine, gps, maps, unityscript

**What I'm doing:**
I'm developing some air traffic control software in Unity 3D using unityscript.
I need to map aircraft locations via GPS cords to map tiles rendered on polygons.

**What I have done:**
I have a map tile rendered on top of a polygon and the origin point is in the top left of the polygon.

**What I need:**
I need a method to convert GPS cords to a pixel vector so I can place an icon of a plane on top of that pixel. I'm using MapQuests tile server at a zoom value of 15 and GPS data to get the tile.

Each tile is 256x256 and the units in unity are measured in pixels.

I have done quite a bit of research on how this is done and I haven't found anything that suits my needs unfortunately!

Here is an example of the above:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/anTGh.png